# Rest API authentication failure - Jenkins

Tags: java, rest, jenkins, jersey

I have installed Jeninkins on port 8081 and setup admin user with user name and password as 'admin'

I am getting the below error while trying to call rest API to get the list of jobs manually created using Java client

ERROR : "GET http://localhost:8081/api/xml returned a response status of 401 Unauthorized"

Can you help to resolve the issue with authenticating the user.

My Java client :

```
        String url = "http://localhost:8081/api/xml";
        String name = "admin";
        String password = "admin";
        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
        Client restClient = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(url);
        ClientResponse resp = webResource.accept("application/xml")
                                         .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
                                         .get(ClientResponse.class);
        if(resp.getStatus() != 200){
            System.err.println("Unable to connect to the server");
        }
        String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("response: "+output);
```

Comment: 401 error that means you have an authorization problem. Check if your settings.xml have the <username> and <password> entries correctly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it by adding API token in the Jenkins url.PBF,working code snippet

```
    String url ="http://<user name>:<apitoken for user>@localhost:8081/api/xml";
    String name = "admin";
    String password = "admin";
    String authString = name + ":" + password;
    String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
    System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);
    Client restClient = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(url);
    ClientResponse resp = webResource.accept("application/xml")
                                     .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
                                     .get(ClientResponse.class);
    if(resp.getStatus() != 200){
        System.err.println("Unable to connect to the server");
    }
    String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println("response: "+output);
```